# Android: ImageView won't be loaded

Tags: android, imageview, android-xml

I have been looking all over stackoverflow to find a solution, but I haven't found it. So now I want to say sorry if duplicate is found. Now that I have said that, let's get some code and problems:

I am trying to load an `ImageView` into my Activity, but I keep getting a nice blue debug log in my logcat saying `"imageview == null"`

```
if (imageview == null) { 
    Log.d(TAG, "imageview == null");
 } else {
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bm); }`
```

which just checks if my `ImageView` is null or not (and sets an image into it if not null). I try load it in the `onCreate` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.confirmpicture);
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("GalleryImage");
    Log.i(TAG, "Got " + str + " from the intent");
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(str);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galleryPicture);
    if (bm != null) {
        if (imageview == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "imageview == null");
        } else {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap not decoded");
    }
```

My head keeps asking me: "Did you declare the ImageView in the xml file, you fool?" and I keep checking the xml file which contains

```
<ImageView
    android:name="@+id/galleryPicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/confirmText"
    android:contentDescription="description comes here...." />
```

I am targetting API 8 (Android 2.2) and I have been trying to fix this problem about loading the `ImageView` for days now. Fixed now

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the right layout here (setContentView(R.layout.confirmpicture);) ?

Comment: Please check the str object or getIntent().getStringExtra("GalleryImage") may one of this giving you null

Comment: Yes Nunu, I am loading the right layout file.

Comment: I write out what's in the str object Pratik in the Logcat, and I haven't heard that a String can be null, only that it can be empty ("")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `android:id="@+id/galleryPicture"` in the xml file, not `android:name="@+id/galleryPicture"`. There is no view with id galleryPicture in the layout file you created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `android:id="@+id/galleryPicture"` instead of `android:name="@+id/galleryPicture"` and also set the image in imageview as below:

> ```
> <ImageView
> android:id="@+id/galleryPicture"  <------ set proper id.
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="100dp"
> android:layout_below="@id/confirmText"
> android:background="@drawable/someimage" <------Set background
> android:contentDescription="description comes here...." />
> ```